# WinMobile устройства. Настройка сети по IP. Работа 2 и более устройств с компьютером одновременно.

Tags: mobile-development, config, сеть

Cтолкнулся с проблемой подключения к сети 2 и более устройств одновременно.

Устройство отправляет запрос на локальный компьютер по IP.
Есть программа ActiveSync которая помогает соединить 1 устройство, но одновременно с несколькими она не работает. Как я подозреваю, можно выставить где-то в настройках строгий IP, но как это сделать, не знаю, так как вроде даже и получается, но результата нет. Если кто разбирался, помогите пожалуйста сконфигурировать сеть.

Ps. может `Windows Mobile Device Center` поддерживает несколько устройств одновременно, но я не могу проверить, даже Google об этом чего-то молчит. Наверняка нет поддержки.

Answer (score 1):

решил вопрос подключением через специальный craddle. также можно один через activeSync, другие к примеру по wifi на ip.